toggle options -> xaxis -> type from "datetime" to "category" make xaxis labels show numbers
I want to display a graph with two types of data on the x-axis.
One with strings and another with timestamp.
At initialization I have no problems but once I switch from datetime to category the x axis displays numbers instead of strings.
Use radio button to switch from "Date" to "Lot" in the example.
code : https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/4lgy3d
I tried 2 methods to update the options by going through a state and using the method "updateOptions".
